# Call function from reference of C++ Object in JS (V8)

Tags: c++, v8

I have next JS code:

```
my_cpp_object.my_function(); // Works fine
var func = my_cpp_object.my_function;
func(); // Error, callback have not pointer to C++ object
```

This code should work fine in theory. But not in case the `my_cpp_object` is object which I create by `v8::ObjectTemplate` and `v8::Context::Set()`, because objects that I add to context by this way stores pointers to C++ object instance. 
And when I call `my_cpp_object.my_function()` it's call a callback function with `const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&` argument which have pointer to C++ object.

But when I call func() it's call a callback with `const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&` argument too, but there is no pointer to C++ object (`args.Holder().As<v8::Object>()->InternalFieldCount() == 0`)

Is it possible to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code should work fine in theory

Unfortunately, no.
In JavaScript, having a receiver matters for method calls. You can think of it as an implicit first argument. Assigning an object's method to a variable "loses" the receiver. In other words, the `func` variable does not remember that it was loaded from `my_cpp_object`, so the `func()` call has no way of passing a pointer to this object along with the call. Consider this pure-JavaScript example:

```
var o = {
    x: 42, 
    get: function() { return this.x; }
}
o.get();  // 42
var func = o.get;
func();  // undefined
```

(The reason you get `undefined` is because in the `func()` call, the global object will implicitly be the receiver, so the `.x` load will load a non-existing property from that, so you get `undefined`.)

In short, if your C++-defined method relies on `args.Holder` or `args.Receiver` for anything (or if your JavaScript-defined method relies on `this` in any way), then the call must have the right receiver.

Any solution to this must happen on the JavaScript side. If you need a way to store only a single function, you can create a closure to capture the receiver:

```
var func = function() { return my_cpp_object.my_function(); }
func();  // Works fine.
```

Comment: It is very helpful answer! Thank you for the explanation!